# How do I create an unitialized object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, initialization

I'm working on a wizard that uses javascript to change the page in an iframe.  I'd like to create an object for each page of the wizard with references to a next & previous page.

**Edit:  The code posted below does not work.  actionOne.nextAction is equal to {} after execution.**

```
var actionOne = {};
var actionTwo = {};

actionOne = {
    url: 'actionOneUrl.htm',
    prevAction: null,
    nextAction: actionTwo,
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action One');
    }
}

actionTwo = {
    url: 'actionTwoUrl.htm',
    prevAction: actionOne,
    nextAction: null,
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action Two');
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to properly set up the next and previous references.  There is likely a relatively simple solution, but I'm not sure what to search for.  I am able to set the references after creating all the pages, but it feels very clunky to do so.  Is there a way to do it while creating the objects?

Comment: You basically want to do what you've done but without the first two lines?

Comment: maybe you can implement a function inside the objects and pass the reference through the function

Comment: @ExplosionPills No, what I've posted doesn't work.  nextAction & prevAction are always equal to '{}'.

Comment: You should take a look at the MVC pattern... :-D

Comment: @natlee75 Perhaps that is true, but I'd also like to learn the way objects really work in javascript :)

Comment: @natlee75: What does the MVC pattern have to do with any of THIS??? (rhetorical question, the answer is "nothing") :-(

Comment: @samspot What aspect of objects are you interested in? I don't think I comprehend exactly what issue you're having with JavaScript objects, but I'd like to help if I can.

Comment: @Mörre Depending on what he's trying to accomplish on the page the MVC pattern could be quite useful in setting up the type of wizard behavior he's looking for. That was based on his original question although in his comment reply to mine I surmise that his question lies in something else.

Comment: @natlee75: A workaround is easy to create using some functions, but MUCH more interesting would be a deeper explanation of the underlying issue, which, by the way, he laid out quite nicely. You throwing around "MVC" does not show that you see the issue, which you yourself just admitted above.

Comment: @natlee75 I want to reference an object that hasn't been 'filled out' yet.  So when i do 'a.prop = c', then 'c = { x: "foo"}', I want a.prop.x to be "foo".  Right now a.prop is undefined.

Comment: @samspot Gotcha. The problem here as you probably know is that when you assign the brand new object literals to the `actionOne` and `actionTwo` variables you're essentially "cutting ties" with the original values of the variables so the `nextAction` property of the `actionOne` literal is set to the empty object literal you originally assigned to `actionTwo`. The `prevAction` property of the `actionTwo` literal does, however, have the expected and proper reference to the `actionOne` literal.

Comment: @samspot As you can see from all the answers you've gotten it doesn't seem like there's a way to set up these relationships "while creating the objects" as you requested. I haven't seen a solution to this particular problem myself in my years of experience with the language although honestly I've never had a requirement to not create relationships between objects after they've already been created... sorry.

Comment: @natlee75 Thanks for your help!  I'd also like to add that a lot of the answers posted were very helpful and I wish I could upvote more than one.

Comment: I think the real thing you're trying to accomplish with your posted code is using pointers, because you're expecting the value of something to always point to what another variable is pointing to. Which JS doesn't have. It has nothing to do with the way Objects work, it's how variables work.

Comment: JS *has* pointers, implicitly. See my answer below :)

Comment: @Mörre Of course, I was referring to explicit pointers (I'm not sure how JS would work without implicit pointers). But my point is that this question is actually about achieving (explicit) pointers in JS, which you really can't do without some extra code, and still, it's not really true pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're trying to do, you're going to need to use an Object Oriented approach in JavaScript.  This will allow you to assign a reference to new *instances* of your object.  For example this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gq7vQ/

```
function Action(url, name){
    this.url = url;
    this.prevAction = null;
    this.nextAction = null;
    this.name = name;
}

Action.prototype.doDisplay = function(){
    $(".label").html(this.name);
}

var actionOne = new Action('actionOneUrl.html', 'Action One');
var actionTwo = new Action('actionTwoUrl.html', 'Action Two');

actionOne.nextAction = actionTwo;
actionTwo.prevAction = actionOne;

console.log(actionOne.nextAction);
```

---

EDIT: So the OP asked for an implementation that automatically sets up these links between newly added actions.  So here is a doubly-linked list implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/wXC9B/1/

```
function ActionList(){
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
}

ActionList.prototype.doDisplay = function(index){
    var node = this.getNode(index);

    console.log(node.name);
}

ActionList.prototype.getNode = function(index){
    var current = this.head,
        c = 0;

    while(c < index && current !== null){
        current = current.nextAction;
        c++;
    }

    return current;
}

ActionList.prototype.add = function(url, name){
    var node = {
        url: url,
        name: name,
        nextAction: null,
        prevAction: null
    };

    if(this.head === null){
        this.head = node;
        this.tail = node;
    }
    else{
        this.tail.nextAction = node;
        node.prevAction = this.tail;

        //move tail to new node
        this.tail = node;
    }
}

var actionList = new ActionList();

//Each add automatically sets up links between the two
actionList.add('actionOneUrl.html', 'Action One');
actionList.add('actionTwoUrl.html', 'Action Two');

console.log(actionList.getNode(1));

actionList.doDisplay(1);
```

Comment: The convention is to capitalize constructor functions (i.e. `Action`) but good approach apart form that.

Comment: @joeltine Is it possible to do this w/o the 'actionOne.nextAction = actionTwo' portion?  That also works with the code I posted above.  I'm starting to get the impression that what I am trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Yes, what you're asking for is essentially a doubly linked list implementation.  If this were the case, you could simply implement a "add" method that sets up these links.  I'll edit my example to add this.

Comment: @joeltine Thanks, I'm going to mark your answer as the accepted one because I think it really gets at the heart of what I was trying to do.  Thank you for your effort in putting together this example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simplified example, but something like the following structure would prevent the need to manually reference your next/prev actions...let the application logic go find what to do based on the user's inputs.

UnderscoreJS's `where` function http://underscorejs.org/#where would be useful here

```
var dataFromServer = [
  {id:"1", name: "First Page", nextId:"2"},
  {id:"2", name: "Second Page", nextId:"3", prevId: "1"},
  .....];

var actions = [];

var Action = function(data) {
    this.doNextURL = function() {
        //find action with id= data.nextId;
        var actionToDo = _.where(actions, {id: data.nextId})[0];
        window.location.href = actionToDo.url; //or something... a callback parameter, or returning the action rather than doing the 'ui logic' here would be better real world
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < dataFromServer.length; i+=1){
  actions.push(new Action(dataFromServer[i]));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the user actions are a next & previous button with no new data from the server.  Background is that we are adding a wizard on top of a complex existing process.  I will upvote this as it is helpful, but my question is really about object creation and references.  I just posted the wizard stuff as background info.

Comment: @samspot: Understood. Just trying to approach the problem from a different angle in the hopes your 'pairing' of actions could be automated with logic.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
actionTwo = {
    // ...
}
```

you are assigning a new value to `actionTwo`. It does not refer to the object anymore you assigned in `var actionTwo = {};` and hence does not refer to the object you used in

```
actionOne = {
    // ...
    nextAction: actionTwo,
    // ...
}
```

The easiest way would be to just initialise both objects and then assign them to the correct properties later on:

```
var actionOne = {
    url: 'actionOneUrl.htm',
    prevAction: null,
    nextAction: null,
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action One');
    }
};

var actionTwo = {
    url: 'actionTwoUrl.htm',
    prevAction: null,
    nextAction: null,
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action Two');
    }
};

actionOne.nextAction = actionTwo;
actionTwo.prevAction = actionOne;
```

If you want to do this for multiple actions, you should consider using constructor functions, so as [joeltine shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14759073/218196).

---

To learn more about objects, have a look at [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1):

Try this: don't create NEW objects for actionOne, actionTwo, instead leave your code as is - but assign to object properties of the already existing objects (which the first two lines create).

```
var actionOne, actionTwo;

actionOne = {
    url: 'actionOneUrl.htm',
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action One');
    }
};

actionTwo = {
    url: 'actionTwoUrl.htm',
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action Two');
    }
};

actionOne.prevAction = null;  //could also be set above
actionOne.nextAction = actionTwo;

actionTwo.prevAction = actionOne;
actionTwo.nextAction = null;  //could also be set above
```

**Your question was a very good one** - don't let anyone tell otherwise :) It is NOT obvious, even with quite a bit of JS background, that the object properties point to the objects the variables pointed to at the time the (literal) object creation statement was executed, rather than to the variable itself (in which case your example would have worked).

And please ignore the MVC pattern thing, even if it was even upvoted. Nothing wrong with MVC (sometimes), but this is a much, much MUCH more basic Javascript question, those pattern things come into play on a whole different (higher) level than your little interesting issue.

Some background: Deep inside the bowels of the Javascript execution engine variables that have an object as value are pointers (C/C++ background knowledge is good for understanding Javascript, because JS engines are written in it). So, when you assign the value of such a variable to an object property it will not point to the variable, but instead it will receive the pointer the variable has at value at the time. This means if the variable gets a new object assigned, pointing to another place in memory, the object property keeps pointing to the old object. If it pointed to the variable instead it would there find a pointer to the new object. As you can see, answering your question leads us deep inside how Javascript engines actually work on a very low level :)

All the other answers sure also solve your immediate issue, but I believe knowing this bit of background is much more fertile, in the end. Instead of trying to just give an answer that works it's sometimes worth investigating what's really going on... :)

Primitive types are stored in the variable directly, variables for objects are actually pointers. new String("foo") is an object (String), "foo" is a primitive type (string).

**The exact same issue is important to keep in mind when calling functions in Javascript!** It is call by value always, technically - but when the variable is a pointer to an object the value IS the pointer, which one must consider when assigning to variables the function gets as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  I think by using {} I was hiding the new keyword and confusing myself about what was going on.  In my mind I was mutating the object instead of replacing it.  Great answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the only way to accomplish this is to manually set up references between the objects "after the fact." I don't see a way to set the relationships up "while creating the objects" as @samspot originally asked in his question... :-(

Comment: You were not hiding the "new" keyword, which you did not use and is not necessary to create an object (the object literal "{}" syntax is encouraged for plain objects). You were creating a NEW object, overriding what the variable pointed to previously - but the previous object was what the object property pervAction (etc.) still pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `{}` object literal to define an object you are creating a new object instance with the Object constructor.

The following creates two new object instances from the Object constructor:

```
var actionOne = {}; // object instance 1
var actionTwo = {}; // object instance 2
```

This next part creates **another new object instance** (the third object instance) from the Object constructor and adds several properties. `actionOne.nextAction` points to the object instance of `actionTwo` (which doesn't have any of its own properties).

```
actionOne = {
    url: 'actionOneUrl.htm',
    prevAction: null,
    nextAction: actionTwo,
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action One');
   }
} // object instance 3
```

So now when you declare `actionTwo = {....}` it **creates a fourth object instance** with a bunch of new properties. `actionOne.prevAction` still points to the second object instance you created (but are are no longer referencing with the the global variable actionTwo).

The key to remember is that the object literal `{}` creates new object instances with the Object constructor and the properties you create reference the object instance at the time they are declared.

Comment: No, the key to remember that the property does not point to the variable, but to what the variable was pointing to at the time the literal object creation code was executed! The variable itself holds a pointer (deep inside the JS engine), so the object property gets that pointer copied instead of being a pointer to the variable.

Comment: @Mörre I agree that understanding that the property points to an object (rather than copies the object or pointer) is vital, but I think it's even less obvious that `{}` is equivalent to `new Object()`. Without knowing that the `{}` creates new objects one might interpret `{}` as merely syntactic sugar for applying new properties (something like `$.extend()`).

Comment: Yeah, but at least for people with C/C++ background a lot of confusion also about certain Javascript call-ba-value-or-by-reference issues can be cleared up VERY quickly if one tells them how variables are actually implemented in the (mostly C and C++ based) Javascript execution engines, while all the "Javascript only" explanations can be quite confusing. Okay, I've no idea which explantion is easier for people completely unfamiliar with C/C++ (like total beginners who start with Javascript as first programming language).

Comment: @Mörre My first course was in C++ and I've been doing Java for 10 years.  Sometimes it gets in the way with these types of languages.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to really be overcomplicating this.

```
function Wizard(o) {
    return { url:o.url, doDisplay:function() { $('.label').html(o.html); } };
}
var wizards = [{url: 'actionOneUrl.html', html:'Action One'},
               {url: 'actionTwoUrl.html', html:'Action Two'}].map(Wizard);
    // wizards now contains an array of all your wizard objects
wizards.reduce(function(p,c) { c.prevAction = p; return p.nextAction = c;  });
    // prevAction and nextAction now point to the right places
```

Comment: To get this to work I had to add 'return c;' at the end of the callback function in reduce.

Comment: @samspot Good catch, I only tested with 2 elements. You can actually just put the return before the assignment of c.

Comment: Yes and no - things like this can be a great opportunity to point out underlying principles. If all you want is "just a solution" then you need less - but... oh well, I'll leave it unsaid :)

Comment: @Mörre I hear you, but 2 things (1) Javascript is a functional language and class-oriented principles aren't really the appropriate fit here and (2) Generally I find that people appreciate and learn faster by exploring concepts for themselves instead of absorbing theoretical "shoulds".

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with your #1 point. The accepted answer? Well, it IS the accepted answer. And MY answer has ZERO "should", it just says what the JS execution engine does. So I don't understand where you are going. Nor do I know where you suddenly get the map and the reduce functions from (I know map/reduce, just not where YOU got them from HERE) - but the OP does so that's too bad for me...

Comment: @Mörre You have given a lot of great information in the questions here, but you sound kind of hostile.  The main reason I liked this answer is because map/reduce finally made sense to me because of it.  Also, this implementation makes changing the pages exceptionally easy.

Comment: @samspot: I AM an angry white man (but definitely not angry at non-whites, I actually believe Africans have the superior genome) :)
Why do you respond anyway, I don't see where YOU are going either, it is YOUR question, do you think I'm mad because you did not pick MY answer??? Oh my god. I'm a grownup! Also, I (deliberately) did not write (just) for you but for all those searching this site later.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't, but you can keep the empty objects and just fill them:

```
var actionOne = {};
var actionTwo = {};

actionOne.url = 'actionOneUrl.htm';
actionOne.prevAction = null;
actionOne.nextAction = actionTwo;
...
```

But that's rather ugly. I would recommend filling in the links between them by using a function like this:

```
function chain() {
    var i, prev, curr;
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        curr = arguments[i];
        if(prev) {
            prev.nextAction = curr;
            curr.prevAction = prev;
        }
        else {
            curr.prevAction = null;
        }
        prev = curr;
   }
   if(curr) curr.nextAction = null;
}


var actionOne, actionTwo;

actionOne = {
    url: 'actionOneUrl.htm',
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action One');
    }
}

actionTwo = {
    url: 'actionTwoUrl.htm',
    doDisplay: function(){
        $('.label').html('Action Two');
    }
}

chain(actionOne, actionTwo);
```